# Is this sentence correct? "If I were you I would be looking for a new job"

Tags: grammar, be, would

Was asked to translate this question from italian to english, teacher marked it as wrong but I sometimes see people using this formula (I would be looking for...) so is it correct or not?

Comment: Were you given a reason by the teacher for it being wrong?

Comment: It's completely correct. I think your teacher might have been confused by the proscription [don't use continuous tenses for stative verbs](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/stative-verbs), but the phrasal verb *looking for* is not a stative verb.

Comment: @BillJ Nope, she just said it makes no sense at all and that I should have written "If I were you I would look for a better job" if I remember correctly

Comment: @HellixS It might have been a word-for-word translation your teaching was asking for. But you went the smart way and used the most common interpretation. You're both right.

Comment: As Peter said, it is a perfectly idiomatic English sentence. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i%20would%20be%20looking%20for%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: @vickyace In that exercise I was asked to give some hypothetical advice for different situations, one of them was: "Your friends earns too little, give him some advice" so I wrote "If I were you, I would be looking for a new job", error.

Comment: Surely some of this is tense - "would look for" suggests that it's a task that hasn't yet started; "would be looking for" suggests that the task is already underway. Since you wrote it, you know what you meant, and the teacher is wrong to argue as your grammar is fine.

Comment: "would be looking for" suggests that you should already have started looking, while "would look for" is a recommendation that you should start looking now. But it's a very subtle difference, and not all people use it with those nuances.

Comment: @ProfYaffle "would be looking for" **does not** suggest that the task is already underway: it suggests that the task **should** already be underway, as mentioned by Barmar.

Comment: You have to 1. Give us the meaning of the sentence you had to translate, and  2. Say what the "correct" version was. Honestly, the "right" translation  could be: "**Had I been** you, **I would have looked** for a new job" or "If I had been in your shoes, I would have looked for a new job" or "I **might have looked** for a new job, if **I had been** in your situation"  OR " If it **had been** me, **I'd have looked** for a new job". Who's to say that your teacher was wrong if you don't provide more context?

Comment: I've only just read the OP's comment which clarified everything. (Must read comments before making an ass of myself...) May I suggest that the OP edit the post and add what the right answer was supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely correct in modern spoken English

Perhaps your teacher is being stringent regarding the use of "if"?

"Were I you" is historically preferred where the conditional forms the matrix clause, with "if" preferred in secondary clauses.

To me this sounds more pedantic, and worse, than your usage

Answer (score 0):

There should be a comma after the 'if' clause:
If I were you, I'd be looking for a job.

Comment: @ PJMcCombie  Can you supply a rule for this? Answers are expected to be well researched and supported by evidence.